# SELECT WHERE in asp web forms

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I'm having a lot of issues with ASP Web Forms at present I'm trying to get data from a database and filter it based on what the user enters in the textbox of a form.

I've got this so far at the moment it will select the data from the database if I remove the last bit with the query about created by but as soon as I start trying to filter by the created by it says must declare the scalar variable @1. I'm just hitting my head against a brick wall at the moment

```
@{
    var db1 = Database.Open("<database name>");
    var selectCMD = "SELECT CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Description, LeadSourceCode, CreatedOn FROM LeadBase INNER JOIN LeadExtensionBase ON LeadBase.LeadId = LeadExtensionBase.LeadId WHERE (CreatedOn BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd, - 140, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE)) AND (LeadExtensionBase.new_GenActivity = 0)";

if(!Request.QueryString["searchId"].IsEmpty()) 
{ 
    searchTerm1 = Request.QueryString["searchId"];
    selectCMD = "SELECT CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Description, LeadSourceCode, CreatedOn FROM LeadBase INNER JOIN LeadExtensionBase ON LeadBase.LeadId = LeadExtensionBase.LeadId WHERE (CreatedOn BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd, - 140, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE)) AND (LeadExtensionBase.new_GenActivity = 0) AND (LeadBase.CreatedBy = @1)";
}
var selectedDBdata = db1.Query(selectCMD, searchTerm1);
```

}

```
    <form method="get">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Employee ID</td>
                <td><input class="id" name="searchId" type="text"/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Date From</td>
                <td><input name="searchDF" style="cursor: text" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Enter Date To</td>
                <td><input name="searchDT" style="cursor: text" value=""/></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="submit" value="Filter"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </form>

            @if (!Request.QueryString["searchId"].IsEmpty() ) {
            <table class="data-table">
                <tr>
                    <th>Company Name</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Lead Source Code</th>
                </tr>
                @foreach(var row in db1.Query(selectCMD)){
                    <tr>
                        <td><input class="tdtext" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="@row.CompanyName"></td>
                        <td><input class="tdtext" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="@row.FirstName"></td>
                        <td><input class="tdtext" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="@row.LastName"></td>
                        <td><textarea class="tdtextbox" readonly="readonly">@row.Description</textarea></td>
                        <td><input readonly="readonly" class="tdtext" type="text" value="@row.LeadSourceCode"></td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </table>
                }
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing @1 in selectCMD to @0

The first object passed into db1.Query(selectCMD, searchTerm1) is mapped to @0 and not to @1

Comment: Yeah I've also tried that, I've moved on for the time being with a less efficient solution but as long as I get a solution working for now I can sort out the efficiency at a later date. I just need to show some progress

Answer (score 0):

Try by removing @1 in second select query, because you haven't declared @1 to any where in your part. If you still get any issues let me know.

Change like this,

```
selectCMD = "SELECT CompanyName, FirstName, LastName, Description, LeadSourceCode, CreatedOn FROM LeadBase INNER JOIN LeadExtensionBase ON LeadBase.LeadId = LeadExtensionBase.LeadId WHERE (CreatedOn BETWEEN CAST(DATEADD(dd, - 140, GETDATE()) AS DATE) AND CAST(DATEADD(dd, -7, GETDATE()) AS DATE)) AND (LeadExtensionBase.new_GenActivity = 0) AND (LeadBase.CreatedBy = @1)
selectCMD.Parameters.AddwithValue("@1",'"+TextBox1.Text+"'); // Your textbox values
```

Comment: Thats what I need to do though I need it to pull data out based on the value of a text field

Comment: Then remove 1 and instead of that use your textbox values. Now you Check my answer . I have edited.

Comment: NEVER use your textbox.Text directly in your query.
Use parameterized queries to prevent SQL-Injection

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to do @Dooie but it's not having any of it

Comment: @Crouch check it now.